# How can I do instructions (like with a messagebox.showinfo) but using icons inside it?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

Basically I am building a program and I have a message box that shows the instructions. However, since the program is based on icons, such as, when we have a ruler, it means it does distances, I want to put in that message box the ruler icon in order to explain what it does, but I am not being able to insert the icon in the messagebox.showinfo. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have code? It needn't be your full application just a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't think you can change the icons in messagebox easily. A easier approach might be just to create a class that spawns a `Toplevel` widget that accepts title, message and icon as parameter.